# Magento 2 Varnish on Nginx server

Tags: magento, magento2, varnish

Have installed Varnish cache successfuly but now when I try to use: systemctl status varnish - it's giving me an error Could not get socket :80: Address already in use.

I have checked the sockets by using netstat -plntu and it seems like that this is the problem:

**206.189.99.109:80**  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 31889/nginx: master

10.18.0.8:8080  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 31889/nginx: master

206.189.99.109:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 31889/nginx: master

one of the Nginx: master is running under port 80 I have tried to change the port in nginx config files but nothing.

How or where can I change this port to 80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `nginx`, you have to change to port in the config file that holds your vhost config.

Usualy `listen 80` is somewhere in that file. Replace it with `listen 8080`.

For `varnish`, the listen port is part of the `systemd` config file. By default it is hosted in `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service`, but it should be copied to `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service`.

In the `varnish.service` file you'll find something like `-a :6081`, which should be replaced by `-a :80`.

After you've made the changes to the `varnish.service` file, you need to reload the `systemd` daemon by running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

And finally, it's a matter of restarting `nginx` & `varnish` using the restart commands that `systemd` offers.

Here's the all-in-one command that does all this for you:

```
sudo sed -i 's/80/8080/' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo cp -f /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service
sudo sed -i 's/-a :6081/-a :80/' /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart varnish
```

These are my assumptions about these commands:

- Your `nginx` vhost conf file is `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`
- Your `varnish` is in its *out-of-the-box* config, and still listens on port `6081`

Comment: when I run the first command I am getting an error: No such file or directory

Comment: instead of sites-enabled I have a directory there called sites-available and inside there I have default, but even I changed this in the command I did not get a result, still port 80 is in use by nginx

Comment: Solved but had to move nginx on port 80 and varnish at port 8080. Big Thanks!

Comment: I modified my `sed` command in the answer I gave you, because I realize that `nginx` adds 2 listen ports to the config file: 1 for IPv4 & 1 for IPv6.

The fact that `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` doesn't exist could be a problem, because `nginx` bootstraps configurations from that folder.

Please try again, because Varnish is supposed to run on port 80.

Comment: All good except I had to use port 80 for NGINX and 8080 for Varnish. This way when someone visits a non-https URL, I can use the 2nd server block on NGINX vhost in making a 301 redirect to https